# NativeScript is WebView an WKWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nativescript, wkwebview

I have build an app with an NativeScript WebView and all working good. But the **speed** performance of the content inside the WebView is much **slower** then in for exemple Safari.

**main-page.js**

```
var createViewModel = require("./main-view-model").createViewModel;
var webViewModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/web-view");

function onNavigatingTo(args) {

  var page = args.object;
  var webView = page.getViewById("webview");
  webView.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function () {});

  webView.src = "https://google.com";

  page.bindingContext = createViewModel();

}


exports.onNavigatingTo = onNavigatingTo;
```

**My question is:**

Is NativeScript WebView an UIWebView? And if so, how do I get the UIWebView to and WKWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript 3.4+ uses WKWebView.

Comment: Sweet.. just updated both NativeScript and the App to latest version. Do you know why the WebView is till rendering the JS action slower then normal WKWebview?

Comment: I did update an answer to my question about the slow performance in WebView. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781789/nativescript-3-4-webview-on-ios-performance-is-slow