# NativeScript 3.4: WebView on iOS performance is Slow

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, nativescript, wkwebview

When I open an site in the WebView on NativeScript 3.4 & 4.0 the performance of the JavaScript is slow. Much much slower then normal WKWebView when build in Xcode.

I have also tried the NativeScript playground ([play.nativescript.org](https://play.nativescript.org/)) and if you place out an WebView an run an some site with JavaScript it also have slow performance.

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se this: [github](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5683#issuecomment-381489047).

> The issue might be related to the JavaScript which is set up to
>   config the site's initial-scale.Just for the test I would suggest
>   opening node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/web-view/web-view-ios.js and
>   replace var jScript = "var meta = document.createElement('meta');
>   meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content',
>   'initial-scale=1.0');
>   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"; -> var
>   jScript = "" then try to build the project again tns run ios and check
>   if the javascript will be executed slowly again.

This make it work great! Thanks to @tsonevn!